# DNS Cache using PHP

Tags: php, caching, dns

I was just wondering if there is a way using PHP in retrieving the contents in your DNS Cache.. Especially the domain names that are already in your cache and its corresponding IP Address.. Is there a way in PHP that could retrieve this and probably display it in your browser..

Example the DNS Cache contains the ff:

```
www.google.com
10.10.10.1

www.yahoo.com
1.1.1.1
```

Is there a way that I could actually print the content and display it in the browser?

Comment: PHP running where?  PHP usually runs on the web server, and that certainly _won't_ have access to your local DNS cache.

Comment: yes.. I am using xampp for the development of my project.. and I want to have the content of my cache.. The websites stored there and its corresponding ip address..

Answer (score 0):

Access to the DNS cache depends on what operating system you're on.

I believe there are methods to enumerate the local cache on Windows-based systems, but I've never seen anything like that for the mini caching daemons sometimes used on Unix systems to gateway between `gethostbyname()` and the real DNS.

However if you've got a real BIND server running, you can get a dump of its cache by running:

```
rndc dumpdb -cache
```

(assuming you have the appropriate security keys set up to allow `rndc` to talk to `named`).

Comment: Now I read this I have the impression that I've seriously misunderstood the question... In that case, the Windows command would be `ipconfig /displaydns`. Its output need some simple parsing.